# Permissions for production environment in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

These are the permissions that I have applied to my system in the development mode:

```
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :www-data .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Are these permissions correct for the development environment? Should I leave it for the production mode should the permissions be different? Do we have to do something else to use production mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to the Magento2 documentation for file permissions on development and production environments: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

The permissions do differ between production and development.

Here are other links for the overview of ownership https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html and command examples based on your server https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html.

In your example you're adding write privileges to those directories. That's a development environment permission setting. On a production environment (once you have production mode enabled) you're going to want to do something like this `find app/code lib pub/static app/etc generated/code generated/metadata var/view_preprocessed \( -type d -or -type f \) -exec chmod g-w {} + && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php`. If you need to run updates to components or upgrade Magento you'll need up open up the permissions again with this `find app/code lib var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc \( -type d -or -type f \) -exec chmod g+w {} + && chmod o+rwx app/etc/env.php`.

Comment: I have already checked that part of the manual and I can not understand it, so I ask if someone gives me a summary answer

Comment: Gotcha, here are other links for the overview of ownership (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html) and command examples based on your server (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html). This should provide the clarity you're looking for. Based on your example it looks like you're going with the two users as opposed to shared hosting.

Comment: Yes but I found this page where you can see the orders to give permissions that I put up, and I'm not clear if these are the right ones for production too https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Your current example is for development because it's adding write privileges. See the update to my answer with more detail.